# Redirect realtime common line output to Django HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

In a long run command line execution, like uncompressing a large .zip archive, how to redirect the realtime output of unzip command to browser via Django's HttpResponse?

**EDIT:**
According to paul's suggestion, I did a search and found this question has answers to how to return a HttpResponse by using a generator.

[[Update HttpResponse Every Few Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754922/update-httpresponse-every-few-seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754922/update-httpresponse-every-few-seconds)

Now, remaining problem is how to capture and create a generator from the output of unzip.

Comment: You might look at this ticket for ideas: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpResponse constructor takes either a string or an iterable.

To trickle content down, you can make the iterable a generator.

Provided, of course, your middleware isn't interfering.